# Irreducible fatorization of $X^n-1$ in both the ring of polynomials with complex coefficients and real coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) = x^n-1$ be a polynomial in $\Bbb R[x]$. Factorize $f(x)$ as a product of irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb C[x]$ and show that if $n$ is even, $f(x)$ has two reals roots and if $n$ is odd, $f(x)$ has one real root.

---

Can someone help me? I know that a polynomium of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ complex roots and that I need to factorize it as a product of $n$ degree $1$ polynomials with $x-a_i$ where $a_i$ is the $i$'th root. But how do I determine the complex roots? And do I have to use the fact that complex roots always come in pairs with its complex conjugated? 
I know that if $n $is even the are two real roots $1$ and $-1$ and if $n$ is odd the only root is $1$ with multiplicity of $2$.

Comment: This should help : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity .

Comment: I edited your post to properly $\LaTeX$ify it.  Remember to surround your $\LaTeX$ with "\$" signs; thus \$ x^n - 1 \$ yields $x^n - 1$ etc.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The complex roots are the $n$-th roots of unity, which you determine with the exponential form of complex numbers: they have modulus $1$ and their argument must satisfy 
$$\bigl(\mathrm e^{i\theta}\bigr)^n=\mathrm e^{in\theta}=1=\mathrm e^{i\cdot0}\iff n\theta\equiv 0\mod 2\pi\iff\theta\equiv 0\mod\frac{2\pi}n,$$
taking into account that the complex exponential function has period $2i\pi$.

Can you proceed and show there are $n$ roots of unity and determine  which pairs are conjugate?